# Continuing work with QT

Tags: visual-studio, qt, open-source

I've been doing a fun project using a trial verion of QT Creator (QT 5.9). The trial ended, is there any way of continuing the work? I have heard of an open source verion of QT libraries. How do I use them? For example in visual studio 2017? Is there any sort of a replecemnt for QT in creating a window applications?

Comment: Ask one question at a time. Also the only possible answer to the questions like "how do I use them" is RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first and most important question: An open source package of Qt is available under the terms of LGPLv3, also for Windows. The [Qt licensing page](https://www1.qt.io/licensing/), where you'll also find links to advanced topics, states:

> The Qt open source licensing is ideal for use cases such as open source projects with open source distribution, student/academic purposes, hobby projects, internal research projects without external distribution, or other projects where all (L)GPL obligations can be met.